# Edit one dataframe by 2 columns matches in two df in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello everyone I need some help in order to fill some 0 values in a `df2`
according to a `df1`

Here is the **df1** :

```
COL1  COL2      COL3     COL4
Chr1  C.lupus   4083.0   66.0
Chr2  C.lupus   6.0      13.0
Chr4  C.lupus   96.0     0.0
Chr7  C.lupus   90.0     0.0
Chr8  C.lupus   875.0    11.0
```

here is the **df2**

```
COL1   COL2       COL3     COL4  COL5
Chr1   C.lupus    0        0     A
Chr2   C.lupus    0        0     B
Chr3   C.lupus    0        0     C
Chr4   C.lupus    0        0     D
Chr5   C.lupus    0        0     E
Chr6   C.lupus    0        0     F
Chr7   C.lupus    0        0     G
Chr8   C.lupus    0        0     H
Chr9   C.lupus    0        0     I
Chr1   S.cattus   0        0     J
Chr2   S.cattus   56       0     K
Chr3   S.cattus   0        0     L
Chr4   S.cattus   0        8     M
Chr5   S.cattus   2        0     N
```

and the idea is to fill `COL3` and `COL4` values of **df2** according to `COL3` and `COL4` values of **df1** if `COL1` and `COL2` corresponds in bot dataframe.

at the and I should get :

```
COL1   COL2       COL3     COL4  COL5
Chr1   C.lupus    4083.0   66.0  A
Chr2   C.lupus    6.0      13.0  B
Chr3   C.lupus    0        0     C
Chr4   C.lupus    96.0     0.0   D
Chr5   C.lupus    0        0     E
Chr6   C.lupus    0        0     F
Chr7   C.lupus    90.0     0.0   G
Chr8   C.lupus    875.0    11.0  H
Chr9   C.lupus    0        0     I
Chr1   S.cattus   0        0     J
Chr2   S.cattus   56       0     K
Chr3   S.cattus   0        0     L
Chr4   S.cattus   0        8     M
Chr5   S.cattus   2        0     N
```

Thank you very much for your help and time

I saw this post : [pandas update specific rows in specific columns in one dataframe based on another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352269/pandas-update-specific-rows-in-specific-columns-in-one-dataframe-based-on-anothe)

but here I need two column matches in order to edit df2 (COL1 and COL2)

Comment: Then use `df.set_index(['COL1','COL2'])` ;)

Comment: instead `df.set_index('COL1')`